# Multi platform (android/iphone) chat

Tags: iphone, android, chat

I would like to add a chat feature to my application, which runs on both iphone and android platform.
Do you have any idea on how to make this ?

I have seen that tutorial : http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/, but I don't know if it will work using the android NDK

I have also think about writing the architecture client/server in C but I'm not sure if it's the good solution ..

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: I have to ask, is this really something u need? With so many good messaging apps out there, is it worth the coding trouble? You will have to write code for a server to conect the various cell phones.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Xmpp standard:

http://xmpp.org/

You can set up an existing xmpp server:

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/

and the use existing libraries for your iphone / android applications:

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Answer (score 0):

I know that comet works fine on iPhone but never tried it on Android.
You should check this blog post: ["Android chat using jetty cometd"](http://blogs.webtide.com/dyu/entry/android_chat_using_jetty_cometd).